# "Completion type" for IPython Console in Spyder

Tags: spyder

I'm a new Python user and I'm just playing around with customizations in Spyder. This question is just out of curiosity.
I saw that when I go to Tools > IPython console > Display there's a drop down menu under "Completion Type" that allows the user to "Decide what type of completion to use", and gives 3 available choices (Graphical, Terminal and Plain).
I googled around and tried switching between the 3 of them but I can't get a hang of what are the differences between the 3 of them. Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They relate to how suggestions are displayed when you press tab. e.g. I type keras.layers. then press tab, it'll show the possible completions, the completion type refers to how these suggestions are displayed

Based on my observations,

Graphical = a box that you can scroll through

Terminal = text style (displayed below code) that cutoffs at some point

Plain = text style that does not cutoff

Note: You need to restart your IPython consoles to see the changes.